# Правильна ли расстановка запятых в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Для тех, кто не является сотрудниками строительной фирмы "Акро", филиала и компании "Аркада", – 5 355 руб.

Comment: А какой знак вызывает вопрос? Запята перед тире? Ну да, без неё "красивше", но она нужна, поскольку парная.

Comment: Безымянный филиал, если принадлежит фирме, нужно определить как «её».

Comment: Тут другое... двусмысленность появляется. Получается, что речь идет о тех, кто не является *одновременно* сотрудниками всех трех названных предприятий...

Comment: @shampar а черт его знает, кто там кому принадлежит. ))) Я бы тут вообще посоветовал отредактировать капитально всю фразу (см. выше мой коммент).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильна.

> Для тех, ***кто не является сотрудниками строительной фирмы "Акро",
> филиала и компании "Аркада",*** — 5 355 руб.

Две запятые открывают-закрывают придаточное (выделено), после "Акро" — между однородными членами.

Answer (score 0):

Просто уточните, какая взаимосвязь между строительной фирмой "Акро" и компанией "Аркада". Возможно, что "Акро" и есть филиал компании "Аркада". Тогда союз "и" в вашем предложении это опечатка, так как говорят "филиал компании". Если есть еще некий "филиал", который не относится к компании "Аркада", то нужно указать филиал какой компании.